# Mercurial equivalent of svn's merge --record-only?

Tags: mercurial, pull, svn-merge

We've recently moved our codebase from subversion to mercurial, and are doing our first release to production from the mercurial codebase this weekend.

We have a three repo setup, let's call them *dev*, *stable* and *release*, where *dev* is a clone of *stable* and *stable* is a clone of *release*. At the moment, *dev* has our version 7 code, and *stable* has our version 6 code. We've just pushed the version 6 code to *release*. Our next release, version 6.1, is scheduled for next week.

The problem is that, since we're also doing a major upgrade in the v6 release, we're expecting to release multiple times (6.0.1, 6.0.2, etc) before the 6.1 release. Going forward this won't be a problem as all three repos will have different version numbers, but right now both *stable* and *release* are v6.

If I change the version numbers in our poms on *stable* to 6.1, this change will have to be pulled back to *dev*, which will mean fixing it there before any of those artefacts can build (so as to not pollute the v6.1 release with what are really v7 artefacts).

Is there a way to tell mercurial to pull this change into *dev* without actually accepting the change, similar to what svn's merge --record-only does? Is the only option to pull the change to *dev* and then do a backout?

Thanks

Comment: When I say it won't be a problem in the future I mean we can make these point releases without making version number changes in the codebase, since the version numbers in the codebase are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I follow your version-management logic; what do different version numbers have to do with which changes you pull or merge? But if I understand you correctly, you want to modify the explicit version number in the `stable` branch (say, to 6.1), then continue pushing changes to `dev` but prevent the version number of `dev` from becoming 6.1.

Here's how you do it: Make sure the version number is in its own changeset-- you don't want it sharing a changeset with changes that you *do* wish to apply. Now merge this changeset, telling mercurial to always use the "local" version of a file during the merge by means of a special "merge tool":

```
hg merge --tool internal:local -r REV
```

As `hg help merge-tools` explains:

```
A merge tool combines two different versions of a file into a merged file.  
...  
"internal:local"  
    Uses the local version of files as the merged version.
```

See the full help for the details.

Merging revision `REV` will also merge any changesets that `REV` depends on. So you should first merge the revision immediately before `REV` (in the normal way), if necessary. This could be automated with

```
hg merge -r 'parents(REV)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like I said, this is not how we normally manage version numbers or releases, it's a one-off due to transitioning to mercurial and the huge upgrade happening in this release.